# Erlang, working with Tuples without BIFs

Tags: loops, erlang, tuples

is there a way to iterate over Tuples or get an Element of a Tuple without using BIFs? And i need to do this without using any other Data type like lists or maps or something else. 
I did a lot of research but found nothing. :(
Thanks!

Comment: "without BIFs" means just pattern matching? And the tuples are of fixed length or arbitrary length?

Comment: yes, i mean without functions like "element(N, Tuple)" or "size(Tuple)". And it must works with all tuples no matter how many elements they have.

Comment: and yes, just pattern matching! :) for example its easy to iterate over a list with [H|T]. But is there a similar way for tuples?

Comment: Why can't you use `element(N, Tuple)`? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: yes the prof says we don't know what goes on behind the scenes when we use this function.

Comment: maybe i've misunderstood this task? is it possible to implement functions like "element(N, Tuple)" in Erlang? Because as far as I understood this correctly, functions like these are implemented in C right?

Comment: Correct. `element()` is in the `erlang` module and is implemented in C. To get an element of a tuple, use pattern matching. Iterating over a tuple doesn't make much sense because tuples are typically used to group items of differing types. If you *really* need to iterate, the best way is a recursive function that uses `element(N, Tuple)`. You could also make a massive function that pattern matches on a large number of different sized tuples. Finally, there may be a way to use macros that would expand to the value, but that's an exercise for you.

Comment: Oh, by the way, congratulations on going to a university that teaches Erlang! I thought Java or C++ was what everyone was taught these days. :)

Comment: okay nice, thanks alot for your help! :)

Comment: @RichN, guess, your comments suitable as answer for the question.